# Why can you change the value of a local variable in Ruby in a function using another method but not with an assignment operator?

Tags: ruby, variables, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm trying to understand the concept of Ruby as a pass-by-reference-value language. Using an example I found on [this](https://launchschool.com/blog/object-passing-in-ruby) site...

```
def uppercase(value)
  value.upcase!
end

name = 'William'
uppercase(name)
puts name
```

we get the output "WILLIAM". So value and name are both pointing at the same object, which is initially holding a value of "William" and then .upcase changes it to "WILLIAM". I would understand this as pass-by-reference.

But then if I change `.upcase` to `=`:

```
def uppercase2(value)
  value = "WILLIAM"
end

name = 'William'
uppercase2(name)
puts name
```

The output becomes "William". Which is pass by value.

Why does an assignment operator make the difference in how a variable is treated in Ruby?

Comment: Rule of thumb is _you can never change `self`_. If `value = "WILLIAM"` _did_ mutate, that in effect be changing the value of `self` for that value right? Therefore it's not possible, and Ruby re-assigns the variable instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is that you can never change a Ruby object's core `self`, once it has been created it will always be the same object until garbage collected and destroyed. It is only possible to alter *properties* of the object.

You can, however, change *variables* or object references such as instance variables, constants, `attr_accessor` properties among other things.

So in this case:

```
def uppercase2(value)
  value = "WILLIAM"
end
```

This reassigns the `value` local variable. It does nothing to the original *object*.

If you want to replace that text you need to use methods on the object to effect it, if supported. In this case there is a method:

```
def uppercase2(value)
  value.replace("WILLIAM")
end
```

These are generally termed *in-place modifications* as in the object itself is manipulated rather than swapped for another object.

Comment: ...or `value[0..-1] = "WILLIAM"`.

Comment: I am confused by what you are trying to say. Your first sentence is "you can never change a Ruby object", and then in your second code snippet, you demonstrate how to change an object, which seems to directly contradict your first sentence.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I mean you can't change the object itself, its fundamental `self` as in `object_id`, but you can change object *properties*, like a `String`'s content.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to understand the concept of Ruby as a pass-by-reference-value language.

Ruby is pass-by-value. Always. It is never pass-by-reference. The value that is being passed is an immutable unforgeable pointer, but that is *very* different from pass-by-reference.

C is pass-by-value. And C has pointers. That doesn't mean that if you pass a pointer in C, it magically becomes pass-by-reference. It is still pass-by-value.

C++ has pointers, *and* it supports both pass-by-value and pass-by-reference. In C++, you can pass pointers by value or by reference and you can pass non-pointers by value or by reference. The two concepts are completely orthogonal.

If we can agree that C is pass-by-value, and we can agree that C has pointers, and we can agree that when we pass a pointer in C, that is still pass-by-value, then we must also agree that Ruby is pass-by-value, because Ruby behaves like a hypothetical version of C, where the only allowed types are "pointer to something", the only way to access a value is dereferencing the pointer, and the only way to pass a value is taking the pointer.

That does not change parameter passing in C in any way, which means it is still pass-by-value, which means if we call that in C pass-by-value, it doesn't make sense to call it anything else in Ruby.

> ```
> def uppercase(value)
>   value.upcase!
> end
>
> name = 'William'
> uppercase(name)
> puts name
> ```
>
> we get the output "WILLIAM". So value and name are both pointing at the same object, which is initially holding a value of "William" and then .upcase changes it to "WILLIAM". I would understand this as pass-by-reference.

Again, this is *not* pass-by-reference. Pass-by-reference would mean that you can *change the reference in the caller's scope*, which Ruby does not allow you to do.

This is nothing but simple mutation. Ruby is not a purely functional language, it does allow you to mutate objects. And when you mutate an object, you can observe its changed state regardless of what name you call it.

My friends call me "Jörg" but my barber calls me "Mr. Mittag". When my barber cuts my hair, it doesn't magically grow back when I meet my friends, it will still be gone even though they don't refer to me by the same name as my barber does.

You have two names for the same object, and you mutate that object. You will observe the new state regardless of which name you use to refer to that object.

That is simply "mutable state", it has nothing to do with pass-by-reference.

> But then if I change `.upcase` to `=`:
>
> ```
> def uppercase2(value)
>   value = "WILLIAM"
> end
>
> name = 'William'
> uppercase2(name)
> puts name
> ```
>
> The output becomes "William". Which is pass by value.
>
> Why does an assignment operator make the difference in how a variable is treated in Ruby?

It doesn't. Both cases are pass-by-value. In the second case, you created a new object and assigned it to the local variable `value` inside the `uppercase2` method. (Technically, it is not a local variable, it is a parameter binding, but it can be rebound inside the method body, *precisely because* Ruby is pass-by-value. If it were pass-by-reference, then this would have *also* reassigned the `name` local variable to the newly created object.)

Sometimes, this *specific* case of pass-by-value, where the value being passed is an immutable pointer to a potentially mutable object is called *call-by-object-sharing*, *call-by-sharing*, or *call-by-object*. But that is *not* something different from pass-by-value. It is *still* pass-by-value. It is a special case of pass-by-value, where the value cannot be "any value" but is always "an immutable unforgeable pointer".

Sometimes, you will hear the description "Ruby is pass-by-value where the value that is being passed is a reference" or "Ruby is pass-by-reference-value" or "Ruby is pass-by-value-reference" or "Ruby is pass-by-object-reference". I don't really like these terms, because they *sound* very close to "pass-by-reference", but actually the term "reference" in "pass-by-reference" and the term "reference" in "pass-by-object-reference" *mean two different things*.

In "pass-by-reference", the term "reference" is a technical term that can be thought of as a generalization of the concept of "variable", "storage location", etc. Wheres in "pass-by-value-reference", we are talking about "object references", which are more like pointers but cannot be manufactured or changed.

I also don't like the terms that I used above "pass-by-value where the value being passed is an immutable unforgeable pointer", because the term "pointer" has certain connotations, especially for people coming from C. In C, you can do *pointer arithmetic*, and you can cast a number to a pointer, i.e. you can "conjure up a pointer out of thin air". You can do none of that in Ruby. That's why I add the adjectives "immutable" (no arithmetic) and "unforgeable" (you cannot create a pointer, only be handed one by the system), but people overlook or ignore them or underestimate their importance.

In some languages, these immutable unforgeable pointers to objects are called "object references" (which is again dangerous because it invites confusion with "pass-by-reference") or OOPS (Object-Oriented PointerS) which has the unfortunate connotations of the mostly unrestricted free-for-all "C" pointers. (Go, for example, has much more restrictive pointers, but when you simply say the word "pointer", nobody thinks of Go.)

Note that none of this is really specific to Ruby. Python, ECMAScript, Java, and many others behave the same way. C# behaves the same way by default, but also supports pass-by-reference as an *explicit* opt-in. (You *must* explicitly request pass-by-reference both at the method definition and at the method call.) Scala behaves the same way by default, but optionally supports call-by-name.

C# is actually a very good way of demonstrating the distinctions, because C# supports both pass-by-value and pass-by-reference, both value types and reference types, and obviously, you can write types both as mutable and immutable types, so you actually get all 8 possible different combinations and you can study how they behave.

I came up with this simple test code, which you can easily translate into other languages as well:

```ruby
def is_ruby_pass_by_value?(foo)
  foo.replace('More precisely, it is call-by-object-sharing!')
  foo = 'No, Ruby is pass-by-reference.'
end

bar = 'Yes, of course, Ruby *is* pass-by-value!'

is_ruby_pass_by_value?(bar)

p bar
# 'More precisely, it is call-by-object-sharing!'
```

[Here is the slightly more involved example in C#](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LfCecY):

```csharp
struct MutableCell { public string value; }

static void ArgumentPassing(string[] foo, MutableCell bar, ref string baz, ref MutableCell qux)
{
    foo[0] = "More precisely, for reference types it is call-by-object-sharing, which is a special case of pass-by-value.";
    foo = new string[] { "C# is not pass-by-reference." };

    bar.value = "For value types, it is *not* call-by-sharing.";
    bar = new MutableCell { value = "And also not pass-by-reference." };

    baz = "It also supports pass-by-reference if explicitly requested.";

    qux = new MutableCell { value = "Pass-by-reference is supported for value types as well." };
}

var quux = new string[] { "Yes, of course, C# *is* pass-by-value!" };
var corge = new MutableCell { value = "For value types it is pure pass-by-value." };
var grault = "This string will vanish because of pass-by-reference.";
var garply = new MutableCell { value = "This string will vanish because of pass-by-reference." };

ArgumentPassing(quux, corge, ref grault, ref garply);

Console.WriteLine(quux[0]);
// More precisely, for reference types it is call-by-object-sharing, which is a special case of pass-by-value.

Console.WriteLine(corge.value);
// For value types it is pure pass-by-value.

Console.WriteLine(grault);
// It also supports pass-by-reference if explicitly requested.

Console.WriteLine(garply.value);
// Pass-by-reference is supported for value types as well.
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start breaking this down in something more understandable.

You can compare a variable like `name` (or `value`) with a signpost.

[image: signpost]

Let's say I point it to the a beige house, which will be the value of the variable.

[image: beige house]

With the above in mind let's take a look at the first example:

```
# don't worry about this line for now
House = Struct.new(:color)
```

```
def color_red(value)
  value.color = :red
end

house = House.new(:beige)
color_red(house)
puts house
# prints: #<struct House color=:red>
```

So what happens here? When we pass `house` as parameter to `color_red` Ruby will **copy** our signpost and assign it to `value`. Now both signposts point to the same house. We then follow the directions of signpost `value` and walk to the house and paint it red.

For this reason the color of `house` will end up being red.

Now let's have a look at the other example:

```
def color_red(value)
  value = House.new(:red)
end

house = House.new(:beige)
color_red(house)
puts house
# prints: #<struct House color=:beige>
```

Here we start of the same, we **copy** our signpost `house` and assign the copy to `value`. However instead of walking up to the house and painting it, we are going to modify the signpost and point it to a red house somewhere further down the street. And because our signpost `value` is a copy of `house`, pointing it in a new direction will not effect `house`.

---

Your code is doing the same thing. When you call `value.upcase!` you are saying to she string. Hey you, upcase all your characters! (Similar to painting the house.)

When you reasign `value` (`value = "WILLIAM"`) you are essentially just modifying the signpost and pointing it to a new direction. However the signpost is passed as a copy so it does not effect the original.

Answer (score 1):

```
def uppercase(value)
  value.upcase!
end

name = 'William'
uppercase(name)
puts name #WILLIAM
```

In this case, you are mutating the original object. `name` points to `William`
and so does `value`.  When you pass in the argument, Ruby will assign
the parameter variable `value` to the same object that `name` is pointing to.

```
def uppercase2(value)
  value = "WILLIAM"
end

name = 'William'
uppercase2(name)
puts name
```

In this case, you are reassigning `value`.  That is, you are changing which
object `value` is pointing to.  It was pointing to the same string object that
name was pointing to.  But, now, you are asking `value` to reference a
different object.

So, in summary, `upcase!` mutates the object while `=` will re-assign.
You can think of 3 circles, `value` is in one, `name` in another and `William`
in the third.
`value` and `name` both point to the string object, `William`.

In the first situation, you mutate the string object that both `value` and `name`
are pointing to.

In the second situation, you are creating a 4th circle, which has `WILLIAM` in it.  Then you are erasing the line from `value` to `William` and creating a line
from `value` to `WILLIAM`.

You get the idea if I do this:

```
def uppercase2(value)
  value = "WILLIAM"
  puts value
end

name = 'William'
uppercase2(name) # => “WILLIAM”
puts name           # William
```